# Sqlite databse app.db is not present while working with Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sqlite, asp.net-core, .net-core

On creating an ASP.NET MVC project on Visual Studio 2017 community version, the project does not contain an `app.db` file(and doesn't use SQLite by default). On the other hand while creating the same type of project through the dotnet cli by using the following command: `dotnet new mvc --auth Individual -o myMvcApp` creates an `app.db` file and uses the SQLite database by default.

Is there any way in which I can add an SQLite database to the existing solution(project) in Visual Studio? How can I make this process default?

Comment: why not just create it from the command line then open it in VS? I think they make the command line project templates more cross platform friendly whereas VS for windows they use mssql localdb by default. after all they want you to use Azure

Comment: Yeah that's true but then I am not able to run it in Visual Studio. It is throwing some exceptions.

Comment: a project created from dotnet new command should be able to run in VS, if you get unexpected errors I would ask about that and post the error details

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio default template comes with SQL Server Connection string and Configure Services, You can configure `Startup.cs` and `appsettings.json` file to use SQLite DB.

In `appsettings.json` modify `ConnectionStrings` like below.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "DataSource=app.db"
 },
```

Now, In `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureServices` method modify `services.AddDbContext` to use `UseSqlite` like below.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Hope this will help!